# Is it correct to say "underground"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is the following sentence natural?

> I made it to work by underground today.

Comment: You put a question mark at the end of the phrase. Did you mean to?

Comment: Natural (in London), but not necessarily grammatical since The Underground is a specific subway in London.

Comment: Why is this been put on hold as off topic? there is no relevant discussion here in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

## Underground vs. subway

In London, the subway system is known as “the Underground.”  In London, you can say

> I took the Underground.

In other cities, you would say

> I took the subway.

Or, use the local name.

> I took the [“L”.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_%22L%22) (Chicago)
>
> I took the [“T”.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boston_T) (Boston)
>
> I took the Metro. (Paris and Washington)
>
> I took BART. (San Francisco)

## “Made it” vs “take” or go

Your example said “I made it”, which suggests the journey was **difficult, stressful or busy.**

If you just mean “I went,” use “I went, I came or I took”.

> I took the subway.
>
> I went to work by subway.
>
> I came to work by subway this morning.
>
> Even though the weather was bad, I **made it to work** by subway this morning.
>
> Even though there was a long delay, I (still) **made it to work** by 9 am.

Comment: So can I say I get to work by underground"?

Comment: No, see above, say “I take the Underground.”